# problem with diagnostic plots for binary regression

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binary-data, diagnostic

I make a binary regression to study Italy's poverty/non poverty on R.

## mod1<-glm(status~CLETA5+cit+AREA3+Q+studio+ACOM5+godabit,data=total,family=binomial)

I don't know if the diagnostic plots are correct or there are some problem with them.
I never seen first a similar residuals VS fitted plot
[image]

Comment: I don't think the default R diagnostics (you've done `plot(mod1)` right?   I think John Fox Companion to Applied Regression (CAR) and Frank Harrel Regression Modelling Strategies may have some better suggestions.   Do you really have a 1/0 status?   I *think* Frank Harrell might have suggested that you need to group a few observations to get meaningful residuals in that case.

Comment: Yes I used defaukt R diagnostic. I divided the populatation into poor and not poor families to study their features( status:1=poor 0=not poor).I'll inquire about these methods that i didn't konw